# Как настроить переход на конкретный слайд в слайдере на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, слайдер

На главной странице сайта есть слайдер. Он состоит из 4 слайдов, на которых есть кнопки, ведущие каждая на некую новую страницу. Как осуществить обратный переход с этой страницы на слайд с которого была нажата кнопка перехода?

Comment: Используется какая-то JS-библиотека для реализации слайдера?

Answer (score 2):

1. по клику на странице, откуда нужен переход, кидаете нужный номер слайда в куку (можно указать какой-нибудь уникальный ID - найти его в сладере и перейти к нему).
2. на странице (где слайдер) считываете куку, берёте метод вашего слайдра (в доки смотрите) и делает переход к этому слайду
3. удаляете куку

Примерное так:

```
// функция для получения куки
function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

// на странице с которой нужен переход
$('.js_selector_click').click(function(){
  var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 2)); // кука живет 2 минуты
  document.cookie = "id_slide=" + 2 + ";expires=" + date.toUTCString();
})


// на нужнной стрницк - где слайдер
var this_id = getCookie('id_slide');

// метод перехода к слайду
$( '.slider' ).slickGoTo( parseInt(this_id) ); // пример со слайдера slick

// удаляем куку
var date = new Date(0);
document.cookie = "name=id_slide; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
```